# Dialog is difficult... why isn't there a linting tool?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I think this site needs a lot more work for it to become a good open-source code review platform. Otherwise, it will be blind-sided by something else soon enough!

My biggest bug bears are:

- No sane way to integrate with jsfiddle/jsbin.
- Dialog is really really hard.

  [image: Trying to have a discussion in the comments]
- No integration of linting tools.

Comment: Your question is a little... unclear. If you're asking for *site feature requests*, you may want to visit [meta.stackexchange](http://meta.stackexchange.com) and post there. If you could elaborate, or something similar, that'd be appreciated.

Comment: Your feedback is appreciated. However, when posed in this form, there's probably no answer that can make you happy. If you make a separate meta post for each complaint, we can have a constructive discussion on each topic.

Comment: Actually... I have no clue what you want to tell us. It seems to me your goals and CR's goals do not quite match up. This is just fine, but it's hard to understand the reasoning behind your bug bears without you telling us. We aren't telepaths :)

Comment: Regarding the no lint tools, you could also see this meta question: [Tools for format and error checking in your programming language](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/5249/78136)

Answer (score 10):

> *I think this site needs a lot more work for it to become a good open-source code review platform.*

Funny you mention, out of the 112 questions I have asked on this site, 26 are tagged [rubberduck](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rubberduck) - an open-source project... and I'm not done yet.

I've seen a number of alternatives, and honestly, I doubt reddit or anything else is going to slow down CR's growth, which has been [quite phenomenal](http://data.stackexchange.com/codereview/query/161411/site-activity-and-votegraph#graph) over the course of the past two years. If *something else* is going to overtake CR, it hasn't seen the light of day yet.

---

#### No sane way to integrate with jsfiddle/jsbin.

Why would you need a jsfiddle when you can embed the code in a [Stack Snippet](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2450/23788) and run it straight from the post, without a 3rd-party?

#### Dialog is really really hard.

Use comments to ask for clarifications, or [take it to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=codereview.stackexchange.com). I tried very hard, but I can't come up with anything better than a dedicated chatroom to discuss things in details.

#### No integration of linting tools.

This is a Q&A site, not an IDE. I don't see the problem. Copy the code into your favorite IDE, use your favorite tool.

Comment: I meant a good code review platform **for open source** code.

Stack Snipper IIUC is for running code on the page. That's kinda useless. You need HTML/JS/CSS. You need history.

In my opinion the iterations must be captured somehow. Each discussion, each refinement needs to be displayed as a story. Not buried in a chat.

Code review is a lot about linting. Would be nice if there way a straight forward way of extracting a code snippet (raw URL) to be posted to an external linting tool.

Comment: I don't understand. On one hand you're saying you want jsfiddle integration, on the other you're saying running the code is useless. Color me confused.

Comment: Running the inline code only exposes a tiny bit of the overall functionality of a Web app. It needs to be seen as a whole. E.g. https://jsbin.com/bovuyo/

Comment: @KaiHendry In the link you gave, I don't see anything that Stack Snippets cannot do. Am I missing something? Have you actually tried the Stack Snippets?

Comment: Can you give me an example of a whole JS/HTML/CSS Web application as a Stack Snippet please?

Comment: @KaiHendry Note that questions with complete applications are a bit rare, because they tend to be too much for one review. More often we review part by part. But yes, I've seen several complete applications on Stack Snippets, but I will have to search, and I don't have time for that now. You still haven't answered my question. The example you linked, I believe it can fully run on Stack Snippets, easily.

Comment: @KaiHendry [Perhaps this is a good example](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/62583/javascript-minesweeper-with-stack-snippets)

Comment: Ok, it does seem to do the full app, thank you! http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/106814/invoice-receipt-markup

Answer (score 5):

> Dialog is really really hard.

I honestly mean no offense, but have you looked in the mirror?
Your question is like a simple bullet point list with short sentences and a picture. It's like a slide from a presentation, where the speaker explains the listed key items in detail. (I wish all slides were like that!) But this is no slide and no presentation. It's really hard to understand what you're actually asking, and what you already know.

For example in terms of jsbin integration, it's unclear if you're aware of Stack Snippets, or if you have problems with it, what are they.

Your question about dialog was very unclear, even with the screenshot. I had no idea what to make of that screenshot, until I copy pasted your bullet point list in my answer, which revealed the title of the image:

> Trying to have a discussion in the comments

A-ha! Perhaps you were trying to have a discussion, and were disappointed that there was no answer? That's hardly an issue with the framework, but human nature. Also note that this is a Q&A site and not a forum, and discussions in comments are explicitly discouraged. There's (a absolutely superb!) chat for that, and again, it's not clear if you're aware or not.

Returning to the issue of "dialog", I think that first you need to do a bit more at your end.
We're constantly interested in improving our community,
but we also need feature requests to have a good grasp of the existing features,
and use them as a context for possible improvements,
expressed in a bit more detail than one sentence per feature.

Comment: Since I have -1 on my question and judging by your somewhat (no offence) pretentious reply, I do have to wonder if my feedback is indeed valued.

Mat's Mug comments with WIN are a tad arrogant. Oh well, maybe this medium or the culture of its operators are lost on me.

Comment: I didn't mean to be pretentious. Rephrased simply, my point is that the remarks in your question are too short to work with, and seem uninformed. That's just what I meant.

Comment: @KayHendry for the record: your question currently has 1 up and 2 downvotes. In addition you should be aware that meta votes are different. Downvotes are often simply 'I disagree' and **not** 'this question sucks'

Comment: @KaiHendry I've edited the "Win"s out. I didn't mean to be arrogant, but your question - to me at least - came across as a direct attack against the very core/concept of this site. And this site has been my go-to place for the past 2 years, and will remain for the foreseeable future - I might be slightly protective ;-)